# How to connect a user from Google signin to another user who has signed in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an Android app in which the users sign in through Google signin, the logged in users can chat with another logged in users.

The problem is what code or logic shall I write so that if one user enters the email of another user he can connect to him and they both can chat?

How do I check if the person exists who have logged in through my app or do I need to save users in database?

I am using Firebase.

Comment: save them in the database, this is js and an old SDK version, but includes some data structures and should give you an overview of the approaches: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6479129

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides a realtime database that can be accessed by different users (not a connection mechanism between users).

So, rethink your problem. Perhaps you want a user to authenticate and connnect (saving that information in the database); then allow a user to search the database for other users (or for a specific user) and leave a message for that useer (define your database with "fromuser" "touser" and "message").  To read messages a use would query to see if there are any "touser" messages that are for him (and that he has not read).

Not a specific implementation .. but I hope you get the idea.